# Route WAN traffic to router which is placed behind switch first

Tags: routing, vlan, local-area-network, wide-area-network, openwrt

Would be possible to do the following as it is at image?
I would like to send all traffic coming from internet to Router with FW first and then to the LAN.

I thought this could be achieved by using VLAN tagging, is this the way how to do that?
The reason I want to do that in this way:

- There is a data switchboard which is not really suitable for wifi router, so I decided to put there switch with 802.1q support
- There is a start topology from switch board to other rooms at apartment
- Router would be placed on better place right between two floors to effectively cover both of them with WiFi signal

So, my questions:

- Is this correct approach?
- Is this safe approach? I mean will under all circumstances all traffic be routed to the router at the first place? Or will I have to use router instead of switch?

[image: LAN Diagram]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I want to use OpenWRT router as entry point for LAN, so traffic would go through its firewall and the router will be also handling IPv4 NAT for LAN.